# Multi value assertion in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, assertions

I am testin an api response.

The api response contains a parameter courier id .
Which appears multiple times in response, with differnt values.

I need to test if all the values in the response are as expected.

For single value testing i am using
Courier_id : value.

How to modify this to test all the occurances of this parameter in response.

Comment: You can see all the retrieved values in the Debug Sampler. It will display as below.  Courier_id_g, Courier_id_g0, Courier_id_g1 etc.

Comment: Not clear what the problem(s) you'd bumped in? Did you try it at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going for [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project

[image: JMeter JSON Path Assertion]

This way you will be able to perform assertions basing on [JSON Path queries](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

JSON Path Assertion and Extractor can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager JSON Plugins]

Comment: In JMeter 4.0 you don't need the 3rd party plugin (jp@gc) for this. It is just part of the core. There is a JSON Assertion which is 100% the same as the jp@gc one.